# Problema con selenium webdriver y xpath en python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, chromedriver

estoy diseñando en python una automatizacion que me extraiga unos datos de whatsapp web, he investigado y noto que en las ultimas actualizaciones de selenium modificaron unas acciones y son estas:
Selenium 4.3.0

- Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
- Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
- Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
- Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
- Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
- Improved type hints throughout

estoy haciendo codigo peor no encuentro como solucionar el siguiente error

```
**File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\proyectospython\proyecto.py", line 42, in <module>
    contenido1=interesados.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/span[@dir="auto"]').text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements'**
```

mi codigo es el siguiente

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
# driver.get("https://www.google.com")


chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
# driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

# interesados = WebDriverWait(driver,80).until(lambda driver:driver.find_elements("xpath",'//div[@class="lhggkp7q ln8gz9je rx9719la"]')) 
interesados = WebDriverWait(driver,160).until(lambda driver:driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="lhggkp7q ln8gz9je rx9719la"]')) 

numero=[]
fecha=[]
todo=[] 

for interesado in interesados:
    contenido1=interesados.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/span[@dir="auto"]').text
    # contenido1=interesados.find_element("xpath",'.//span[@dir="auto"]').text
    # contenido1=interesados.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@dir="auto"]').text
    numero.append(contenido1)
    contenido2=interesados.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="_1i_wG"]').text 
    # contenido2=interesados.find_element("xpath",'.//div[@class="_1i_wG"]').text 
    # contenido2=interesados.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="_2gsiG"]').text 
    fecha.append(contenido2) 
    contenido3=interesados.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/span[@dir="1qB8f"]').text
    # contenido3=interesados.find_element("xpath",'.//span[@dir="1qB8f"]').text
    # contenido3=interesados.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@dir="_7W_3c"]').text
    todo.append(contenido3)
```

Adicional tengo comentados los cambios que he realizado para hacer seguimiento a toda la programación.

el programama me abre whatsapp web y luego no hace ninguna otra acción

espero su ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
# driver.get("https://www.google.com")


chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
# driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

# interesados = WebDriverWait(driver,80).until(lambda driver:driver.find_elements("xpath",'//div[@class="lhggkp7q ln8gz9je rx9719la"]')) 
interesados = WebDriverWait(driver,160).until(lambda driver:driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="lhggkp7q ln8gz9je rx9719la"]')) 

numero=[]
fecha=[]
todo=[] 

for interesado in interesados:
    contenido1=interesado.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@dir="auto"]').text
    # contenido1=interesados.find_element("xpath",'.//span[@dir="auto"]').text
    # contenido1=interesados.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@dir="auto"]').text
    numero.append(contenido1)
    contenido2=interesado.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="_1i_wG"]').text 
    # contenido2=interesados.find_element("xpath",'.//div[@class="_1i_wG"]').text 
    # contenido2=interesados.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="_2gsiG"]').text 
    fecha.append(contenido2) 
    contenido3=interesado.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="_37FrU"]').text
    # contenido3=interesados.find_element("xpath",'.//span[@dir="1qB8f"]').text
    # contenido3=interesados.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@dir="_7W_3c"]').text
    todo.append(contenido3)
```

Comment: Esto debería ir en tu otra respuesta. No todos ven las respuestas en orden cronológico, por cierto.

Comment: hola jorge, no hay necesidad de llenar de spam la zona de respuestas, puedes responder insertando el codigo cuando creas la respuesta, o bien puedes editarla despues de haberla publicado para insertar el codigo. Pero crear dos respuestas para una pregunta no tiene ningun sentido ni logica... lee [answer]